# iOS - get specific value from plist

Tags: ios, plist

I would like to get the value of NO (from the plist under) into a NSString i got. But I'm stuck.

I used the following code:

```
//Load Dictionary with wood name cross refference values for image name
NSString *plistCatPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Numbers" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *numberDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistCatPath];
self.numberArray = numberDictionary[@"Two"];

// ,[codeForCountryDictionary objectForKey:selectedCountryPicker]
number = [self.policeArray valueForKey:@"NO"];

NSLog(@"Numero: %@", number);
```

But then I got:

```
(
012
)
```

and I only want 012, not with the parentheses.

My Plist:
[image]

Comment: `[self.policeArray valueForKey:@"NO"]` => shouldn't that be `[self.numberArray valueForKey:@"NO"]`?

Answer (score 0):

the "NO" is a NSString key in the "Two" NSDictionary and NSString "012" is the value, for the key "NO"

```
NSDictionary * dict = numberDictionary[@"Two"];
for (NSString * key in dict) {
  NSLog(@"%@ %@", key, dict[key]);
}
```

If you want to get the key for a value from NSDictionary, use

```
NSDictionary * dict = numberDictionary[@"Two"];
NSArray *temp = [dict allKeysForObject:@"012"];
NSString *key = [temp lastObject];
```

Note: allKeysForObject returns an NSArray, as more keys, may have the same value assigned